# How to calculate throughput transaction rate per second using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

How to calculate transaction rate per second10,000 for n current users using Jmeter?

I have added my users and Duration assertion and response assertion

[image]

Is this enough or do I need to add any constant throughput timer or do I need to do any calculations to see the transactions per second?

Answer (score 0):

When you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/testresult.jtl
```

The `testresult.jtl` is a JMeter [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) which contains all the necessary metrics and KPIs, see [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for descriptions of the measurements

In order to get the throughput you can see the throughput for each individual Sampler and overall throughput in i.e. [Summary Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) listener:

[image]

Another option is to use [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond) chart, this way you will see the throughput over duration of the test

[image]

And last but not the least you can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) containing the result statistics table which includes the throughput and charts which also include throughput

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am really confused, when I searched online people have different opinions on the difference between throughput and TPS. I have a requirement where the throughput transaction rate should be 10k per second for 2000 users to test an API. How to check whether I am able to achieve the transaction per second or not.

Comment: Please see the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throughput) for the correct definition of Throughput. TPS is just an expression of this metric (Transaction Per Second). For the second part of your question, a [Calculator](https://ubikloadpack.com/virtual-users-computer.php) might give you an approximation.